# regular expression match _ underscore

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, match

I have a string like this :

002_part1_part2_______________by_test

and I would like to stop the match at the second underscore character, like this :

002_part1_part2_

How can I do that with a Regular expression ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a pattern to match any character but not of an `_` zero or more times followed by an underscore symbol. Put that pattern inside a capturing or non-capturing group and make it to repeat exactly 3 times by adding range quantifier `{3}` next to that group.

```
^(?:[^_]*_){3}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mL6eB8/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.*\d_
```

**EXPLANATION:**

```
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d»
Match the character “_” literally «_»
```

https://regex101.com/r/uX0qD5/1

Comment: This interactive tutorial is great to learn regular expressions: http://regexone.com/

Comment: @GabryRome Which language are you using ?

Comment: How can I do if I want to use your Regex in a shell script ?

Comment: In shell script I changed it in this way :

echo `expr "$string" : '\(.*[0-9]_\)'`

and work great! :-) Many thanks

Comment: Only one thing @PadreoLobito 

what if I have a string like that :

002_Digital_test_______________by_test

??????

Thanks